Cannot run ldd on the primary executable of an MSIX package
I have a traditional (e.g. Win32) app packaged into an MSIX. As part of a CI run, I need to install that MSIX and then use ldd (from msys) to verify that all necessary DLLs have been deployed in the app. I can run ldd on the app's DLLs just fine, but Windows throws a permission denied error if I try to run ldd on the MSIX's main executable. Is there a way I can overcome this?

What does ldd do? Is your app running at the time you try to check it? I just picked an installed package at random, and I can open the EXE with Notepad just fine.
